# Multiple gunicorn apps on different ports with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I am trying to run multiple flask application on localhost.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/app1.sock;
  }
}


server {
  listen 8081;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/app2.sock;
  }
}
```

App1 is accessible at `localhost:80` but accessing app2 at `localhost:8081` results in 404.

Comment: Please post your nginx error.log

Comment: There are no entries in error.log, testing configuration with `-t` returns no errors.

Comment: Your config looks fine. How about access.log ? Or check using broswer developer tools to see if nginx is routing your request to app2 proxy as expected ? Any screenshot showing what you see here will help

Comment: Access log has a bunch of 404s. Also it seems like app2 requests are not routed properly since I don't see the custom header (app name) in dev tools that I set for testing.

Comment: I am interested to see where the request is being routed to and which url is returning a 404

Comment: Not sure what you meant but url is `localhost:8081`, app2 configuration is clearly not working since I don't see the test header I set in nginx conf.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for a 404 entry from access.log and your full nginx conf